# ubuntu failing to boot - could not write bytes:broken pipe

Tags: package-management

So I was having a problem with steam and I went to the steam support center and it told me to delete a file (within the steam directory) next step after that, reboot when I do I am greeted with a black screen saying "could not write bytes:Broken pipe." I have googled this and have tried everything but nothing is working so if anyone knows a solution I would be very grateful

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by providing more information. It would help to know what file you deleted, or failing that even what your question was that brought you to the steam support center. Thank you!